# Outlook.com changing font family in html email

Tags: html, email, font-family, outlook.com

When I use the line with the h3 tag by itself, the correct font is shown.  Once I add the line with the h1 tag, fonts for both are incorrect.  Does anyone know what is going on here?  I'm at a loss.  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<h1 style= "color:#000000; font-family:'Gotham-Light','Century Gothic', sans-serif; font-size: 58px; mso-line-  height-rule:exactly; line-height:58px;margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px; font-weight:normal">How LTCI is Priced
                                                 </h1>

<h3 style="color:#B21F24; font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif; font-size: 32px; font-style: italic; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 100%; text-align: left;font-weight:normal">Dynamics of LTCI Pricing
                                                        </h3>
```

Comment: Best guess is a typo within the h1 style attribute.

Comment: I looked for that but couldn't find an issue with it.  In my pasted code above it breaks apart the mso-line-height, but that is actually pulled together in my css.  Do you see anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook renders html with Microsoft Word's html rendering engine and only accepts certain fonts. The best practice for getting around this would be to chain your fonts how you did.

You already aswered the question but I thought I'd add a bit of the why. :)

https://litmus.com/blog/outlook-2013-still-powered-by-word-now-available-for-email-testing

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer to this - I hope it helps someone else.  Outlook.com didn't like 'Gotham-Light'.  As soon as I removed it everything else worked as expected.